# Compare files line by line to see if they are the same, if so output them

Tags: python, slider, analytics, match, string-matching

How would I go about this, I have files which I have sorted the information in, I want to compare a certain index in that file with an index in another, one problem is that the files are enormously large, millions of lines.  I want to compare line by line the files I have, if they match I want to input both those values along with other values using an index method.

=======================

Let me clarify, I want to take say line[x] the x will remain the same as it is formatted uniformly, I want to run line[x] against line[y] in another file, I want to do this to the whole file and output every matching pair to another file. In that other file I also want to be able to include other pieces from the first file which would be like just adding more indexes such as; line[a],line[b],line[c],line[d], and finally line[y] as the match to that information.

Try 3:

I have a file with information in this format:

#x is a line

```
 x= data,data,data,data,data,data
```

there is millions of lines of that.

I have another file, same format:

```
    xis a line
    x= data,data,data,data
```

I want to use x[#] from first file and x[#] from second file, I want to see if those two values match, if they do I want to output those, along with several other x[#] values from the second file, which are on the same line.

Did that help at all to understand?
The format the files are in are like i said:(but there is millions, and I want to find the pairs in the two files because they all should match up)

```
  line 1  data,data,data,data
  line 2  data,data,data,data
```

data from file 1:

```
 (N'068D556A1A665123A6DD2073A36C1CAF', N'A76EEAF6D310D4FD2F0BD610FAC02C04DFE6EB67',    
N'D7C970DFE09687F1732C568AE1CFF9235B2CBB3673EA98DAA8E4507CC8B9A881');
```

data from file 2:

```
00000040f2213a27ff74019b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 7.3 (32bit)|Linux
00000040f69413a27ff7401b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 8.0 (32bit)|Linux
00000965b3f00c92a18b2b31e75d702c|Localizable.strings|Mac OS X 10.4|OSX
0000162d57845b6512e87db4473c58ea|SYSTEM|Windows 7 Home Premium (32bit)|Windows
000011b20f3cefd491dbc4eff949cf45|totem.devhelp|Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 (32bit)|Linux
```

The order it is sorted in is alphanumeric, and I want to use a slider method.  By that I mean if file1[x] is < file2[x] move the slider down or up depending on whether one value is greater than the other, until a match is found, when and if so, print the output along with other values that will identify that hash.

What I want as a result would be:

file1[x] and its corresponding match on file2[x] outputted to a file, as well as other file1[x] where x can be any index from the line.

Comment: for millions of lines, dict is good enough if you have enough memory

Comment: If you have access to standard POSIX utilities, `comm -12 file1 file2` will output only the lines that are common to both. Is that the end goal? Will you be performing more searches than insertions? Or more insertions than searches?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you really want. Do you want to compare only file1[N] to file2[N], or do you want to compare file1[N] to file2[M], where N and M may or may not be equal? Different parts of your question seem to imply both.

Comment: I don't entirely understand that part either, but it is trivial to change it. Just `seek()` to a different index first.

Comment: @C0deH4cker: It's not necessarily all that trivial -- unless the lines are all of equal length, you need to build an index before you can just seek to a line.

Comment: That's another part about the question that isn't all that clear. An index as in a byte number (an offset) or an index as in a line number.

Comment: Your clarification made it harder to understand.

Comment: @jerrycoffin does it really matter whether its file1[n] or [m] that would only change its value right? Either way you are pulling from two files, I think that's what matters most rather than the actual value I choose.  But yes I what I want is to pull from two files, the index should be of no matter really since it can be changed.

Comment: @C0deH4cker check the last try at me trying to clarify, if you don't understand then I'll see what I can do to further clarify.

Comment: @Larson: the more you 'clarify', the worse it gets... try showing us 5 lines of *actual data* from file1 and file2, and show us what the *actual* final result should look like. Forget the "data,data,data" stuff.

Comment: I don't understand what difference it makes but I will provide the data I am working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I got from the clarification:

- file1 and file2 are in the same format, where each line looks like

  ```
  {32 char hex key}|{text1}|{text2}|{text3}
  ```
- the files are sorted in ascending order by key
- for each key that appears in both file1 and file2, you want merged output, so each line looks like

  ```
  {32 char hex key}|{text11}|{text12}|{text13}|{text21}|{text22}|{text23}
  ```

You basically want the collisions from a merge sort:

```
import csv

def getnext(csvfile, key=lambda row: int(row[0], 16)):
    row = csvfile.next()
    return key(row),row

with open('file1.dat','rb') as inf1, open('file2.dat','rb') as inf2, open('merged.dat','wb') as outf:
    a = csv.reader(inf1, delimiter='|')
    b = csv.reader(inf2, delimiter='|')
    res = csv.writer(outf, delimiter='|')

    a_key, b_key = -1, 0
    try:
        while True:
            while a_key < b_key:
                a_key, a_row = getnext(a)
            while b_key < a_key:
                b_key, b_row = getnext(b)
            if a_key==b_key:
                res.writerow(a_row + b_row[1:])
    except StopIteration:
        # reached the end of an input file
        pass
```

I still have no idea what you are trying to communicate by 'as well as other file1[x] where x can be any index from the line'.

Comment: All I mean is outputting other values that would identify the hash as being from that line, such information like operating system, version #.  "file1[x]" is an example, which means file1 and its index in the list, x just represents a variable which can be any number, that number would identify the positions of the previous items mentioned; OS,Version #.

Answer (score 3):

using this method and comparing compare line by line you don't have to store files in the memory as the files are huge in size.

```
with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2, open('file3.txt','w') as f3:
    for x, y in zip(f1, f2): 
        if x == y:
            f3.write(x)
```

Comment: It's not clear thta this fits what he wants. He says he wants to compare a "certain index" in one file with a certain index in the other. I would take this as asking (for example) whether line 10 of file 1 is the same as line 20 of file 2.

Comment: @JerryCoffin OP also mentioned `I want to compare line by line the files I have, if they match I...`

Comment: Yes, the question seems quite unclear to me, so I've added a comment asking for clarification of that point.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the contents of two files at a specified index:

```
fp1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
fp2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

fp1.seek(index)
fp2.seek(index)

line1 = fp1.readline()
line2 = fp2.readline()

if line1 == line2:
    print(line1)

fp1.close()
fp2.close()
```

Comparing two files line by line to see if they match, otherwise print the line:

```
fp1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
fp2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

line1, line2 = fp1.readline(), fp2.readline()

while line1 and line2:
    if line1 != line2:
        print("Mismatch.\n1: %s\n2: %s" % (line1, line2))

fp1.close()
fp2.close()
```