# Finding matches in two files and outputting them

Tags: python, slider, analytics, match

I want to use x[#] from first file and x[#] from second file, I want to see if those two values match, if they do I want to output those, along with several other x[#] values from the second file, which are on the same line.

The format the files are in :(but there is millions, and I want to find the pairs in the two files because they all should match up)

```
  line 1  data,data,data,data
  line 2  data,data,data,data
```

data from file 1:

```
 (N'068D556A1A665123A6DD2073A36C1CAF', N'A76EEAF6D310D4FD2F0BD610FAC02C04DFE6EB67',    
N'D7C970DFE09687F1732C568AE1CFF9235B2CBB3673EA98DAA8E4507CC8B9A881');
```

data from file 2:

```
00000040f2213a27ff74019b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 7.3 (32bit)|Linux
00000040f69413a27ff7401b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 8.0 (32bit)|Linux
00000965b3f00c92a18b2b31e75d702c|Localizable.strings|Mac OS X 10.4|OSX
0000162d57845b6512e87db4473c58ea|SYSTEM|Windows 7 Home Premium (32bit)|Windows
000011b20f3cefd491dbc4eff949cf45|totem.devhelp|Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 (32bit)|Linux
```

The order it is sorted in is alphanumeric, and I want to use a slider method.  By that I mean if file1[x] is < file2[x] move the slider down or up depending on whether one value is greater than the other, until a match is found, when and if so, print the output along with other values that will identify that hash.

What I want as a result would be:

file1[x] and its corresponding match on file2[x] outputted to a file, as well as other file1[x] where x can be any index from the line. values along with other values using an index method.

Comment: To clarify - not a 1-1 relationship then?

Comment: @JonClements By 1-1 relationship you mean what?

Comment: Equal sized files matchable by key on a line per line basis

Comment: No the files aren't equal in size based on the fact that one provides more information on the other, one serves as basic info for it, and the other is a huge details file.  But the amount of lines is the same, and the information I need from both is in separate files, in a messed up order.

Comment: Didn't you ask this before?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253667/compare-files-line-by-line-to-see-if-they-are-the-same-if-so-output-them

Comment: @Deflect looks very similar :)

Comment: @Deflect I wanted to clarify, and you answered your own question so why ask it? You even provided a link....

Comment: Hang on, the number of lines is the same, but you stated they're in alpha numeric order? (But now in your comment - in a messed up order?)

Comment: @Larson -- oh, sorry.  I was just vaguely curious as to why you asked it again, and forgot to explicitly specify that.

Comment: @JonClements The reason why is because they were ordered in partitions and late merged together into one file, so although those partitions might be in order, the whole thing isn't. That script was simply to clean up the previous format of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starting point, add your own salt and pepper it's far from optimal and should use executemany etc...but that's for you to decide.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv
import sqlite3 as sq3
from operator import methodcaller, itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

data1 = """068D556A1A665123A6DD2073A36C1CAF
A76EEAF6D310D4FD2F0BD610FAC02C04DFE6EB67
D7C970DFE09687F1732C568AE1CFF9235B2CBB3673EA98DAA8E4507CC8B9A881"""

data2 = """00000040f2213a27ff74019b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 7.3 (32bit)|Linux
00000040f69413a27ff7401b8bf3cfd1|index.docbook|Redhat 8.0 (32bit)|Linux
00000965b3f00c92a18b2b31e75d702c|Localizable.strings|Mac OS X 10.4|OSX
0000162d57845b6512e87db4473c58ea|SYSTEM|Windows 7 Home Premium (32bit)|Windows
000011b20f3cefd491dbc4eff949cf45|totem.devhelp|Linux Ubuntu Desktop 9.10 (32bit)|Linux"""

file1 = StringIO(data1)
file2 = StringIO(data2)

db = sq3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute('create table keys (key)')
db.execute('create table details (key, f1, f2, f3)')

for f1data in file1:
    db.execute('insert into keys values(?)', (f1data.strip(),))

for f2data in file2:
    row = map(methodcaller('strip'), f2data.split('|'))
    db.execute('insert into details values (?,?,?,?)', row)

results = db.execute('select * from keys natural join details')

for key, val in groupby(results, itemgetter(0)):
    print key, list(val)
```